# Save histogram during evaluation with estimator api

Tags: tensorflow, histogram, tensorboard

Is it possible to save a histogram during evaluation using the estimator API?

I couldn't find a solution since the estimator api does not write down any summaries during evaluation and I can only add scalars to the evaluates metrics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the sake of those who came here and haven't found a solution, I will update that I used the above approach, with a slight modification:

```
    summary_writer = tf.compat.v1.summary.FileWriter(
        logdir=self.model_dir + '/eval_histograms/',
        filename_suffix='.host_call')
    summary_ops = [tf.compat.v1.summary.histogram(name=k, values=v)
                   for k, v in
                   prepare_endpoints_for_summary(endpoints).items()]
    eval_hooks = [
        tf.estimator.SummarySaverHook(save_steps=1,
                                      summary_writer=summary_writer,
                                      summary_op=summary_op)
        for summary_op in summary_ops]
```

And it worked fine!
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use SummarySaverHook

```
eval_hooks = []

eval_summary_hook = tf.train.SummarySaverHook(
                    save_steps=1,
                    output_dir='model_dir',
                    summary_op=tf.summary.histogram(logits.name, logits))

eval_hooks.append(eval_summary_hook)

return tf.estimator.EstimatorSpec(mode=mode,
                                          loss=loss,
                                          eval_metric_ops=eval_metric_ops,
                                          evaluation_hooks=evaluation_hooks
                                          )
```

Comment: I just found this solution in a issue on the tensorflow github repository. The problem is, I want the histogram in the same file as the other metrics, as they are evaluated together. I'm using streaming metrics, so I try to not have two different evaluations going.

Comment: If I specify model directory in SummarySaverHook, it shows histogram in the same tensorboard plot. This doesn't work with train_and_evaluate, though.

Comment: I was using train_and_evaluate. I guess the problem is, that the custom evaluation hook can't be attached to the evaluation hook which train_and_evaluate uses?

Comment: I don't know exactly why this doesn't work with train_and_evaluate, I guess it somehow overwrites summaries